# Float Fastpow OpenCL

Tags: c, opencl

I'm trying to reduce the logic utilization for my FPGA and I can't find any good float fastpow online. By good I mean with a good reduction of logic utilized. If I use the double version I gain little improvement. If I use other float version that rely on log then again it's little. If I change the double version to float I gain a big reduction but then it doesn't work because results are quite bad. Is there anyone that knows a good approximation of pow for C code? (OpenCL)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I worked on the double version of fastPow and it works the same only using float data types just like this:

```
float fastPow(float a, float b) {
    union {
        float d;
        int x;
    } u = { a };
    u.x = (int)(b * (u.x - 1072632447) + 1072632447);
    return u.d;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to make this function inline (or static), or it won't be fast.